# Is there any way to return battery percentage in the username field in Windows?

Tags: windows

I know that in Windows, (10 at least) that if you type `.\` in the username field of the "other" user login screen, you get the computer name.

Does anyone know if there is a way to return a battery percentage from this field?

Comment: What would be the purpose of this?

Comment: First, understand that `.` is a shortcut that means "this object" or "here". what `.\<username>` means, is that the user account you want resides on the local PC (eg "here"). when logging into a domain, you would indicate `domain\username`. so first, not only would this change almost certainly break login, you are misunderstanding the nature of the input you are entering. login names have a very particular syntax, and all the code that uses those inputs must make many assumptions based on its expectations. it is not simply accessing an arbitrary variable that you can just swap out.

Comment: I work in the IT department at my school, and are frequently charging laptops. It would just add convenience to be able to check the battery percentage without logging into it, that's all. Just a genuine question that's all. I see that the domain slashes and things are the way they are, and how they work, but I just wondered if there were any tricks up its sleeves that's all. Don't think it' worth a downvote...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there is no way to achieve this. Login field accepts several formats of user name, including:

- `username`
- `domain\username`
- `username@domain.name`

With the second pattern (NetBIOS format) the `domain` part can be replaced with a local machine name for local accounts. In addition a dot `.` is used to indicate a local machine in NetBIOS naming.

The fact that you get a local machine name resolved comes directly from the fact that `.\username` is equivalent of `local_machine\username`. It is a vital information for the login process.

On the other hand, neither battery percentage or any other variable that could be used for automation is not used for (not interpreted in) the login field.